What kind of SPDT be used to transfer 120V narrow width signal to SMA connector?
I have a pair of TX and RX. The main objective of this question is that I want to use one antenna for both RX and TX as shown in picture below.

The transmitter is transmitting 120V amplitude pulses with pulse width of 20ns. (The TX circuit is powered by 12V supply. It uses special circuitry to produce 120V pulses using 12V supply).
The receiver will receive signal at amplitude of few millivolts.
i need some kind of SPDT circuit to achieve my objective of using one antenna for both TX,RX. Can I use a relay? SPDT based on MOSFETs? or any other thing? Keeping in mind the supply voltage is 12V and I want to pass 120V amplitude narrow pulses through this SPDT switching circuit.
Thanks for your suggestions.

do you need to switch at  150 kHz? This all very much sounds like a radar application that isn't really following radar application designs

You said your PRF rate is 150 KHz.  Is that the rate at which you need to switch between transmit and receive?  Or is it that you stay in transmit for a long time (seconds or longer), transmitting with a 150 KHz PRF, then switching to receive for a similar amount of time.

And what is the frequency of your transmit and receive signals?  MHz?  GHz?  Makes a big difference in the type of switch needed.

Yes this is GPR application. When 20ns pulse is transmitted, I need to switch antenna immediately to get reflected signal. after that again switch to tx and so on. It is a broadband signal.

Maybe avoid switching between TX and RX altogether? Put a biased (e.g. PIN) diode limiter in bridge configuration followed by a second limiter stage with antiparallel Schottky diodes in front of the receiver and connect it directly to the transmitter. The limiter protects the input of the receiver during transmission while having no impact on the transmitted signal.

@raonoke: Can you share any diagram? I am not getting what you are talking about.

At this point chatgpt gave me answer to my question when no human could. It gave me idea to use circuit used in ultrasound circuits.
This article helped a lot.
High voltage T/R switches protect low voltage ultrasonic circuits

So the answer to my question was using MD0100 Chip.


The digikey article was written by a human expert, not chatgpt.  2) Congratulations on researching the question a bit( Google or ChatGPT, all good), rather than just using others as a crutch.  Research will build expertise, asking for answers won't.  All the best to you

